# Mirrored photo when using front camera

Tags: react-native, image, expo, expo-image-picker

When i take a selfie, with Expo ImagePicker it mirrors the photo. it also saves it mirrored.

result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
cameraType: ImagePicker.CameraType.front,
presentationStyle:  ,
allowsEditing: true,
aspect: [1, 1],
quality: 0.2,
});

Is there any line of code to disable mirror?

I tried presentation style and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to not flip the image when taking the picture, but you can flip it again after the picture is taking, using expo's [`ImageManipulator`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/#imagemanipulatormanipulateasyncuri-actions-saveoptions).

```
import { manipulateAsync, FlipType, SaveFormat } from 'expo-image-manipulator';
```

Then, create a new function and add this (remember to replace `image.uri` with your image uri):

```
const newImage = await manipulateAsync(
    image.uri,
    [{ flip: FlipType.Horizontal }],
    { compress: 1, format: SaveFormat.PNG }
);
```